# Android API Demos 8 Translucent the class is TranslucentActivity.java doesn't do anything

Tags: android, transparency

TranslucentActivity.java doesn't do anything.  There is no translucence, nothing special about it.  It just shows an activity screen.

Comment: Oh come on. I think "Am I doing something wrong, or misunderstanding what this demo is supposed to do?" is a pretty clearly implied question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about what is wrong with the sample.

The very next sample, the Translucent Blur sample after this works, the prior screen is burred...

```
// Have the system blur any windows behind this one.
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);
```

And it shows what it claims to show.

But nothing is done in the TranslucentActivity, about which I am asking.